# Unhandled Exception Type Java

Tags: java, exception, sikuli

I am using Sikuli with Java to create a small automation tool. I am having trouble with this Unhandled Exception error. I am trying to pass a method I created to the GUI actionPerformed method.

```
package mission;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

import tools.ChooseMission;

public class Story {

    public static  void runStoryMissions(int chapter, int stage) throws FindFailed, InterruptedException {
        Screen screen = new Screen(); 
        ChooseMission.ChooseChapter(screen,chapter);
        ChooseMission.ChooseStage(screen, stage);
        int dailyBiometricCount = ChooseMission.dailyBiometricCount(screen); 

        Pattern start = new Pattern("img/chapters/start.png"); 
        Pattern replay = new Pattern("img/chapters/replay.png"); 
        Pattern next = new Pattern("img/chapters/next.png"); 
        Pattern mission_finish_bar = new Pattern("img/chapters/mission_finish_bar.png");


        screen.click(start); 
        System.out.println("The mission has started.");


        Thread.sleep(2000);
        while (find(screen, mission_finish_bar) == false) {

            System.out.println("Still playing the mission...");

        }
        if (screen.exists(mission_finish_bar) != null){
            System.out.println("The mission has finished.");

        }
        System.out.println("Wait for 5 Seconds");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Click repeat button");
        screen.click(replay); 

    }
```

Here is the code for my actionPerformed listener button:

```
btnStartMissions.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int chapter = Integer.parseInt(txtFldChapter.getText()); 
            int stage = Integer.parseInt(txtFldStage.getText());

            System.out.println("Chapter #: " + chapter);
            System.out.println("Stage #: " + stage);


            try {
                Story.runStoryMissions(chapter, stage);
            } catch (FindFailed e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

There is a error at Story. runStoryMissions(chapter,stage) it says: Unhandled Exception type FindFailed and InterruptedException

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at mission.Story.runStoryMissions(Story.java:12)
    at GuiFrame1$2.actionPerformed(GuiFrame1.java:94)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Cannot call method from the event dispatcher thread
    at java.awt.Robot.checkNotDispatchThread(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Robot.waitForIdle(Unknown Source)
    at org.sikuli.script.Mouse.move(Mouse.java:345)
    at org.sikuli.script.Mouse.move(Mouse.java:318)
    at org.sikuli.script.Mouse.init(Mouse.java:59)
    at org.sikuli.script.Screen.initScreens(Screen.java:89)
    at org.sikuli.script.Screen.<clinit>(Screen.java:58)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Okay I posted the stacktrace. I did notice that if I call this method in other classes its fine. I only get this issue when I try to attach it to the GUI button's actionPerformed method

Comment: *Caused by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Cannot call method from the event dispatcher thread*

Comment: This exception related to your runStoryMissions method. Exception throws from line 12 of your meyhod and it is not related to your exception handling. write code of your runStoryMissions() method.

Comment: I updated the post with my code from runStoryMissions. Line 12: Screen screen = new Screen();

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the answer to my problem if anyone is interested.

- Sikuli uses the java.awt features so scripts cannot implement and use Swing elements.
- Java AWT Robot actions cannot be called froma Java swing container.

Solution is to create a new Thread:

```
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Story.runStoryMissions(chapter, stage);
            } catch (FindFailed | InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
```